# Xunit - Check the return value of a method List<P>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing, xunit

I am new to Xunit and I am trying to make a simple Xunit test of a solution I created, I have this method:

```
public List<Countries> GetCountriesValues()
{
    List<Countries> countries = new List<Countries>();

    using (var context = new CountriesDBEntities())
    {
        if (context != null && 
            context.Countries != null && 
            context.Countries.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (Countries c in context.Countries)
            {
                countries.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }
    return countries;
}
```

And I am trying to make a Xunit test case to verify if the return is not null,
But somehow Assert NotNull is not passing, what else should I do?

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GetCountriesValues_TestCountriesReturn()
{
    var actual = mcTest.GetCountriesValues();
    Xunit.Assert.NotNull(actual);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using Fact instead of TestMethod for XUnit?

Comment: What do you mean by "not passing"? Is the assertion hit? Or do you get an exception for something else?

Comment: @user1781290 yes, you're absolutely true, I forgot the fact

Comment: @nvoigt yep, I was trying the real time unit testing and ignored the exception. I forgot to include the Entity.Framework in my test project so the solution was failing because of that. Thank you.

Comment: Remove `if` statement, `context` will never be a `null`, because you just created it. `Countries` should never be a `null` if you follow the convention that all methods which returns a collection will never return `null` but empty collection instead. `.Count > 0` is redundant, because `foreach` will simply do nothing if collection is empty.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other comments, if no conditions are met you are returning an empty list instead of a null.

So you can change your test to check for an empty collection instead of a null by using **Assert.NotEmpty**

```
[Fact()]
public void GetCountriesValues_TestCountriesReturn()
{
    var actual = mcTest.GetCountriesValues();
    Xunit.Assert.NotEmpty(actual);
}
```